# Find distinct pair of two elements such that sum of two equals to 0 in python

Tags: python, sum, unique, distinct

```
def UniquePairs(df_dict, k):
    s = next((x['S.No'], y['S.No']) for x, y in combinations(df_dict, r=2) if abs(x['USD Activity Amount'] + y['USD Activity Amount']) == k)
    final_arr = [x for i, x in enumerate(df_dict) if x['S.No'] not in s]
    return final_arr
```

This function takes a list of dictionaries and finds  n number of unique pair of elements .It is taking hours to run ,I have tested it on few 5 k rows .

Please suggest me an alternative method ?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input data?

Comment: Sno Amount
1 10.5
2 20.53
3 11.45
4 67
5 455.2
6 63
7 28
8 455.2
9 32
10 78
11 54
12 98
13 678
14 -10.5
15 -54
16 32
17 76
18 123
19 -11.45
20 89